# Trouble with custom d3.js based visualization

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm learning d3.js and need to create a visualization mirroring that of the example image I've included in the below fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/mike_ellan/37PYJ/

I know how to create and bind text elements and was planning on doing so for the labeling inside the circles but I'm having a hard time getting my head around how I should be doing it with this particular data structure. I don't have the option to request a flatter json structure so I have to get it mapped out properly as is. Here is the data I'm starting with:

```
var consumption = [
{
    "fruits": [
        {
            "year":"2011",
            "apples":"213",
            "oranges":"176",
            "pears":"987"
        },
        {
            "year":"2012",
            "apples":"199",
            "oranges":"234",
            "pears":"672"
        }
    ]
}
];
```

As for the years, my plan was to generate a 2 row/column table and then add a column for each year based on whats coming back in the json. Can you give me some tips or guidance on how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike this is a quick way to make the graph.

**Create the Columns and append header**

```
// Group Columns
var columns = groupColumn.selectAll("g")
                                    .data(consumption[0].fruits)
                                    .enter()
                                    .append("g")
                                    .attr("class", function(d,i) { return "column - " + i });
              // Append year
              columns.append("text")
                             .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(" + i*(width/2) + "," + height/2 + ")"; })
                             .text(function(d) {return d.year });
```

**Create rows and append fields**

```
 // Append row
var groupRow = columns.append("g")
                             .attr("class", "fruits")
                             .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(" + i*(width/2) + "," + height/2 + ")"; })

 // Append fields of row
var rows =   groupRow.selectAll("circle")
                               .data(function(d) {return d3.entries(d).filter(function(d) { return d.key !== "year"; })})
                               .enter()
                               .append("circle")
                                    .attr("cx",function(d,i){ return (60 * i) + 30 } )
                                     .attr("cy",50)
                                     .attr("r",25)
                                     .attr("fill", function(d){ 
                                        if(d.key === "apples"){ return "red" }
                                        else if (d.key === "oranges"){ return "orange" }
                                        else if (d.key === "pears"){ return "green" }
                                     })
```

**Append Text to Fields**

```
var text = groupRow.selectAll("text")
                            .data(function(d) {return d3.entries(d).filter(function(d) { return d.key !== "year"; })})
                            .enter()
                            .append("text")
                                   .attr("dx", function(d,i){ return (60 * i) + 20 })
                                   .attr("dy", 55)
                                   .attr("fill", "white")
                                   .text(function(d) {return d.value});
```

View code http://jsfiddle.net/jmeza/37PYJ/3/

The example is not complete, I give you the first steps...

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help out!